# Facebook logout url doesn't work via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook

I have a Facebook app that helps users upload a photo taken at an event to their timeline. The users access the app via a public kiosk, so once they've logged into Facebook, authorized the app, and uploaded their photo, I need to log them out at the end so their session doesn't continue to the next user. What I want to do is load the logout url via ajax so that the user can stay on the upload confirmation screen while they are logged out of Facebook behind the scenes. I'm attmpeting to do this via ajax because the confirmation screen contains a lot of values gathered from the upload that I'm trying to avoid passing through the logout process.

However, this doesn't seem to work. I'm generating a proper logout url via getLogoutURL and if I copy its output from the page and load it directly in the browser, the session logs out correctly. But it doesn't seem to work when I try to load it via ajax.

Can anyone confirm that it is or is not possible to log a user out of Facebook via an ajax call to the logout url?

```
<?php
$logout_url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
    'next' => $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sharing/facebook/upload/logout_after.php',
    'access_token' => $access_token
));
?>

var ajax_logout = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax_logout.open("GET", "<?php echo $logout_url; ?>", true);
ajax_logout.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax_logout.send();
```

Comment: I think its a CORS issue. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ . And it makes sense. Otherwise any web application can log you out of facebook :P

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense I guess. So probably no way to do it via AJAX then. Thanks for the info.